# Qt4: How to call JavaScript functions in a page from C++ via QtWebkit?

Tags: javascript, qt4, webkit, call, qtwebkit

I'm trying to write a simple log viewer using Qt4's WebKit port/implementation. My HTML code looks like this:

http://pastie.org/613296

More specifically, I'm trying to find out how to call the add_message() function which is defined in the `<script>` section in the HTML document from my C++ code.

---

```
// Doesn't work:
QWebElement targetElement = chatView->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("head").firstChild("script");

// Function is not included, either...
qDebug() << targetElement.tagName() << targetElement.functions();

// The ultimate attempt in calling the function anyway:
QVariant functionResult = targetElement.callFunction("add_message");
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Qt 4.5 do it something like this:

```
htmlView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("add_message(); null");
```

Note: `null` at the end of script is for performance issue. `QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript` returns `QVariant` with last value in the script. Evaluating last value in the script may be really time consuming, so putting `null` at the end makes it return immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it right away when I get home.
Although that looks like I have to escape the arguments to use them as literals in the evaluateJavaScript() call. Isn't that dangerous or something?

Comment: Yes, you have to escape arguments, becouse JavaScript will generate errors. It shouldn't be dangerouse, becouse you escape it only for JavaScript parser, iniside of webkit it will appear same as unescaped parameter