# Print out webview

Tags: javascript, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

How can we print out what an webview contains? i tried something like :

```
view.page().currentFrame().toPlainText()
```

but it didn't work

PS: my webview contains an evaluation of a javascript function , so i suppose toHtml() won't do the job   any suggestion?

Comment: How do you mean print out? Are you after plain text, rich text, a screen grab? :)

Comment: Actually i wanted the webview to show a result of an execution of a javascript function but i figured lately that this cannot be done unless the function is evaluated in a webpage. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what you're after: do you want to take the numerical/textual output of a js function and use it in your Qt/C++ application, or are you trying to display a webpage with javascript-generated elements?

Comment: I rather want to display a webpage with javascript-generated elements.also i couldn't figure out what event or function should be called and what parameters should i pass to the function to have the expected results in my webview , i tried with some developement tools of browsers like Firebug but i couldn't find how it works ,can you help with an static exemple i heard that i can do that by adding "debugger;" into my javascript code is that true , how could i do this ?thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QtWebKit` will display javascript-generated webpages exactly the same as it will display any other webpage (though you can disable js through [`QWebSettings`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html)). I assume then, that you want the webpage to generate elements based on requests from the C++ application.

If that's the case, you want [`QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript) (as previously stated in this previous question: [Qt4: How to call JavaScript functions in a page from C++ via QtWebkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409522/qt4-how-to-call-javascript-functions-in-a-page-from-c-via-qtwebkit)).

More generally, you might find [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtwebkit-bridge.html) useful.